# Execute multiple NSOperations in parallel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have several methods in various classes in my project say methodA(), methodB(), methodC()... methodZ(). Each method executes network call using NSOperation. There are cases where I have to execute the methods in parallel like methods A, D, M should execute in parallel. Say in another case methods D, S, T should execute in parallel. I maintain a common method in APIManager class which executes all my methods.

I tried creating a operation queue in APIManager class but its not working. Only once a method execution is done, another method execution is happening. Can anyone suggest in this regard?

```
-(void) methodA {

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:kPath, @“Function1”];

NSString *requestXML = [NSString stringWithFormat:kGetFunction1RequestXML];

self.operation = [self.apiMgr requestWithPath:path method:@"POST" xml:requestXML headers:@{@"Accept": @"application/xml", @"Content-Type": @"application/xml"}

                                      success:^(id response) {

                                          NSLog(@“Request successful. Do further handling”);                                              
                                      }

                                      failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@“failed”);                                              
                                      }];
```

}

-(void) methodB {

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:kPath, @“Function2”];

NSString *requestXML = [NSString stringWithFormat:kGetFunction2RequestXML];

self.operation = [self.apiMgr requestWithPath:path method:@"POST" xml:requestXML headers:@{@"Accept": @"application/xml", @"Content-Type": @"application/xml"}

                                      success:^(id response) {

                                          NSLog(@“Request successful. Do further handling”);                                              
                                      }

                                      failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@“failed”);                                              
                                      }];
```

}

```
- (id)requestWithPath:(NSString *)path method:(NSString *)method xml:(NSString *)requestXML headers:(NSDictionary *)headers success:(void(^)(id response))success failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure
```

{

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“%@, self.serverAddress]];

AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:url];

if (headers) {
    for (NSString *header in headers) {
        [client setDefaultHeader:header value:headers[header]];
    }
}

[client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;

request = [client requestWithMethod:method path:path parameters:nil];

[request setHTTPBody:[requestXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];

[operation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:^BOOL(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace)
 {
     return YES;
 }];

[operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge)
 {
     [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
     [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
 }];

[operation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    LogVerbose(@"Background time expired for AFNetworking...");
}];


[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSString *xmlStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *xmlDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlStr];

    if (success)
        success(xmlDic);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (failure) {

         failure(error);
    }
}];

return nil;
```

}

Comment: Try setup maxConcurrentOperationCount on NSOperationQueue instance to number greater than 1. If not settled the system should decide how many operations it can handle at once.

Comment: @Greg, tried doing it also. Still the operations are happening one after another

Comment: This guy has explained NSOperation in nice way, please go through this:https://izeeshan.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/multi-threading-using-nsoperation/

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared any code what you are implementing.

`NSOperationsQueue` only accepts `NSOperation` and you will have to provide `MaxConcurrentOperationCount` property to tell the queue how many operations you want to execute parallelly.

In your case, you defined methods: methodA(), methodB(), methodC()... methodZ(). Each method executes network call using `NSOperation`. But what are you adding in `NSOperationsQueue`, that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: I have edited my question. Could you please verify and provide your comments. I have provided MaxConcurrentOperationCount to 100.

Comment: I declared outside this in my init method                           `self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 100;`